# Validating an object's property using MobX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx

Suppose I have a class like this:

```
class Foo {
  @observable url;
}
```

I want to log a warning if the `url` property isn't a valid URL. I can use `autorun` to listen to the `url` property. When it changes and it's no longer a valid URL, I can log a warning. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [observe or intercept](https://mobx.js.org/refguide/observe.html). In case of `intercept` you even can cancel modification if url is not valid.

```
import {intercept} from 'mobx'

class Foo {
  @observable url;
}

const foo = new Foo();

intercept(foo, 'url', change => {
  const url = change.newValue;

  if (!isUrl(url)) {
    console.log(`'${url}' is invalid url`);
    return null; // cancel modification
  }
});
```

Also `@observe` and `@intercept` from [mobx-decorators](https://github.com/farwayer/mobx-decorators) may be useful for you.

```
import {intercept} from 'mobx-decorators'

class Foo {
  @intercept(change => {
    const url = change.newValue;

    if (!isUrl(url)) {
      console.log(`'${url}' is invalid url`);
      return null; // cancel modification
    }
  })
  @observable url;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution you mentioned is best if you just want to log a warning and not show anything for the user.

**Example**

```
import isUrl from 'is-url';

class Foo {
  @observable url;
}

const foo = new Foo();

autorun(() => {
  if (isUrl(foo.url)) {
    console.warn(`${foo.url} is an invalid URL.`);
  }
});
```